# When you select the Healer connection as a Mystic do you lose access to Mystic Cure?

Tags: starfinder

Under the connection spells entry of Healer it specifically says

> **Spells:**  1st - 6th  mystic cure;  replaced by 1st- lesser  remove
>   condition....

Does this mean that as a Mystic with the Healer connection you lose access to the only healing spell mystics get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

That would be alarming, wouldn't it? I got the same impression from the Healer description. But digging around a bit, I found this text on p. 84:

> If your connection lists a single variable-level spell... you gain that variable-level spell when you first get your connection spell for each level. The next time you gain a connection spell, add the next higher level of the variable-level spell to your list of spells known. You immediately lose the lower-level version of that variable-level spell and replace it with the listed connection spell for that level.

### Huh?

It's still not super well-explained IMO. Let's look at an example. When you hit 4th level, you "first get your connection spell for [that] level", so you get *mystic cure* as a second-level connection (think domain) spell. You then "immediately lose" the first-level version you've been using and replace it with *lesser remove condition*. In other words, the connection spells of a Mystic 4 are *lesser remove condition* and *mystic cure 2*; a Mystic 7 gets *lesser remove condition*, *remove condition*, and *mystic cure 3*; and so on. The result makes sense; it's just awkwardly phrased.

(Note that at higher levels, you can still cast *mystic cure* at a lower level if you want to. So it's good that you get an alternative as well.)